# is there a windows equivelant to storymill?

Tags: windows, software-rec, writing

Came across this great sounding app, but it is only for mac. Does anyone know of anything similar for Windows?

Answers stating "buy a mac" or similar will be downvoted. You have been warned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Alternativeto.net for some ideas](http://alternativeto.net/software/storymill/).

From the site:

[Storybook](http://storybook.intertec.ch/joomla/) is a free, open source novel-writing software for creative writers, novelists and authors which will help you to keep an overview of multiple plot-lines while writing books, novels or other written works

Answer (score 0):

You could always try [MyNovel](http://www.mynovel.biz/)

> MyNovel writing software will help you plan and write your novel. This marvellous novel writing software will encourage you to think about your characters, settings and the events that will form the skeleton of your novel. It will encourage you to visualize your characters and develop your background information before you begin the process of writing. It will organize all your notes, links to research, and diagrams (for instance spider diagrams and family trees) - and of course your manuscript itself - all through one easily navigated and fully integrated interface.